# Why is rnd.Next not giving me the max value

Tags: c#, new-operator

When running this program, the randomly generated numbers never produce the value of x. If the input is a 6 sided dice, rolling 10 times, not a single roll in the 10 will reach six, only 5.

```
internal static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Number of Dice Sides: ");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (!int.TryParse(input, out var x))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That wasn't a valid number.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return;
        }
        Console.Write("How many rolls? ");
        var rolls = Console.ReadLine();
        if (!int.TryParse(rolls, out var y))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That wasn't a valid number.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return;
        }
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine($"{input} sided dice rolling {rolls} times");
        var rnd = new Random();
        for (var i = 0; i < y; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(rnd.Next(1, x));
        Console.Read();

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

`.Next(min, max)` returns the lower bound inclusive and the upper bound exclusive. Here's the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netcore-3.1#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_

In symbols:

```
min <= x < max
```

where `x` is what will be returned.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I've changed the code to this and it works as planned


 `Console.WriteLine($"{input} sided dice rolling {rolls} times");
            const int milliseconds = 2000;
            Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
            var rnd = new Random();
            for (var i = 0; i < y; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(rnd.Next(1, x+1));
            Console.Read();`